# Android Class "this" components

Tags: android, class, variables, field

When I log "**this**" in class methods

```
Log.i(TAG, "this:"+this);
```

the result is:

```
this:android.myapp.MyView{43354c80 V.ED.... ........ 0,9-104,61 #7f0b0005 app:id/myViewID}
```

with fields

**43354c80**  - ?
**V.ED.... ........** - ? some bitfields, V may be Visibility
**0,9-104,61** - clip rect
**#7f0b0005** - ?
**app:id/myViewID** - R.id.*

What means "?" fields of "this" in log?

**=== EDIT ===**

Because all of the comments are not visible, I write complete answer from @Blackbelt answer & comments.

In this case:

43354c80 - result of hashCode()
V - visible
E - enabled
D - depends from setWillNotDraw()
0,9-104,61 - drawing rect
7f0b0005 - result of getId()
app:id/myViewID - id as a string

Comment: `"" + obj` it is always `"" + obj.toString()` ... take a look at the View source to find out what is returned as View's string representation

Comment: "" + obj it is NOT always "" + obj.toString()... when i overwriting toString() to own method

Comment: maybe not always, but in this case the same

Comment: Tapa Save... Yes, it is... Even if you override a toString() method... Operator + with String object and some other non String object will return new String which is split form the String and second object's string representation - value returned form toString()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can image, what you are reading in the log is the override version of `Object#toString()` in `View`:

`V` stays for `View.VISIBLE`

`E` stays for `ENABLED`

```
final int id = getId();
 if (id != NO_ID) {
        out.append(" #");
        out.append(Integer.toHexString(id));
```

it is the View's id toHex. You can read the complete method [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View.toString%28%29)

Comment: You can simply say "#7f0b0005 it is result of getId()". Class reference and string formating are out of question. What is field with value 43354c80?

Comment: it's the view's hashcode

Comment: thanks @Blackbelt 43354c80 its result of hashCode(), #7... getID(), E enabled, the rest of dots I can explain.

Comment: Well, of course the View's hashcode is the result of calling hashcode()

Comment: Don't understand this peoples with -1. All knows this???

Comment: I don't really kwon the reason

Comment: By the way: log in question is printed in onDraw. In class constructor id are the same, clip 0,0-0,0 (I understand it) but hashcode are different from onDraw. Do you know why?

Comment: if the hashcode are different then you are dealing with different instances of the same view

Comment: no, from my logs hashcode in constructor is different like in draw in the same instantion, only id is the same.

Comment: well you could still have two different views with the same id. If you are sure that's not the case, then they are probably taking in account other factors for the calculation of the hashcode.  The code is not available unfortunately

Comment: do you know, what is "D"? drawable? isDirty, isDrawingCacheEnabled, isDuplicateParentStateEnabled are false in my log.

Comment: it is will not draw flag, that for View is not set. D means that is not set (your view will call is onDraw). You can check the doc [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/View.html#setWillNotDraw(boolean))

Comment: OK I see.D depends from setWillNotDraw()